# Let D be a division ring and n≥3. assume that charD≠2. I have to show

Tags: linear-algebra

Let $D$ be a division ring and $n\geq3$. assume that $char D \neq 2$. I have to show the matrix $A \in M_n(D)$ is a non-scalar involution if and only if $(A+I)/2$ is a non-scalar idempotent matrix.I know a matrix $T \in M_n(D)$ is called an involution if $T^2=I$.

Answer (score 0):

Let if $A$ is an involution i.e. ($A^2=I$) then obviously $((A+I)/2)^2=(A^2+I^2+2AI)/4=2(A+I)/4=(A+I)/2$, so it is idempotent.

Conversely, Let $(A+I)/2$ be an idempotent then $(A^2+I^2+2AI)/4=(A+I)/2 \implies A^2+I+2A=2A+2I \implies A^2=I$.

Comment: The matrix ring is **not** a division ring if n is larger than 1.

Comment: Hmmm right. I ll edit